# How to use a serialized or json_encoded attribute in a MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I'm stumped. I want to store either a `serialize()`'d or `json_encode()`'d array in MySQL using a stored procedure. This would be to store a user's checked boxes or multiselect options.

We are using stored procedures, and while I like to think I've gotten a good grip on them over the last few months, I'm not sure how to solve the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'One","Three","Two"]")' at line 1 (SQL: CALL CategoryFieldValues_UpdateAttributeByID("3077", "1", "1234", "field_value", "["One","Three","Two"]"))

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `CategoryFieldValues_UpdateAttributeByID`(
  IN siteID INT UNSIGNED,
  IN ID INT UNSIGNED,
  IN modifiedByID INT UNSIGNED,
  IN attribute VARCHAR(255),
  IN attrValue VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN

    SET @d = IHaveAFunctionHere( siteID );
    SET @n = 'null';

   IF attribute = "category_field_id" THEN SET @n = 0; END IF;

    SET @s = CONCAT(
    'UPDATE ', @d,'.category_field_values cfv
       SET
        ', attribute, ' =  ', QUOTE(NULLIF(attrValue, @n)), ',
        modified_by = ', QUOTE(modifiedByID), '
    WHERE cfv.id = ', ID, ';'   );

PREPARE statement FROM @s;
EXECUTE statement;
SELECT ROW_COUNT() AS ROW_COUNT;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;

  END$$
```

This procedure takes information like the siteID, which it uses to find the right database, and an `attrValue` that is the value I want to set. It works fine, but now when I need to drop a json_encoded or serialized array at it, it chokes.

The json_encoded array ends up looking like `["One","Three","Two"]`.

I'm guessing it's bugging out because of unescaped quotes or square brackets, but I'm not totally sure.

Also, I tried a slightly different syntax (below) to no avail:

```
    BEGIN

SET @d = IHaveAFunctionHere( siteID );
SET @n = 'null';
SET @attrValue = attrValue;

IF attribute = "category_field_id" THEN SET @n = 0; END IF;

SET @s = CONCAT(
    'UPDATE ', @d,'.category_field_values cfv
       SET
        ', attribute, ' =  ?,
        modified_by = ', QUOTE(modifiedByID), '
    WHERE cfv.id = ', ID, ';'   );

PREPARE statement FROM @s;
EXECUTE statement USING @attrValue;
SELECT ROW_COUNT() AS ROW_COUNT;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;

  END
```

I've also tried removing the `QUOTE`s, and some other small tweaks, and I'm just spent.

Comment: Hi you can use `encode()` `decode()` , `add_strip()` method

Comment: Try: `CALL \`CategoryFieldValues_UpdateAttributeByID\`('3077', '1', '1234', 'field_value', '["One","Three","Two"]');`.

Comment: Great thanks for the suggestions @codeBloger and wchiquito - sorry for the delay it's been a busy week. Let me give these a spin and I'll get back to you both. <3

Comment: Also ^ thanks @wchiquito - I didn't realize I could only tag one user per reply.